# Change allowed file types based on certain criteria

Tags: entities, nodes

An admin comes onto the website and creates an **assignment** which is a content type.  Students come onto the website and create **submissions** that point to the certain **assignment**.  There is a **file upload field** where students can upload their submission.  I want to make it so when the admin creates the **assignment**, he/she can choose which **file types are allowed**.  Is there a field that will automatically process what file types the admin chose so that a student can only upload that specific file type?

Comment: Hi. I don't think that it's possible to do it via some module. But I can provide step by step instruction for developer, how to do it. Is it suitable for you?

Comment: Yes, I prefer to do most of the stuff on the website in my own custom modules, could you provide an explanation? @Eugene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it's the rough instruction step by step as Matt asked:

1. Add new field where you can specify the allowed extensions of the files.
2. Alter the form of your submission via hook_form_alter() and find your file upload field [image]
3. Specify your allowed extensions from your field with extensions into this point

Comment: What application did you use to find all of this field information? Sorry, I'm pretty new to Drupal.

Comment: It's PHPStorm in debug mode